# error syntax with T element != default(T)

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

my problem is with this code:

```
class LinkedList<T>
    {

    Node<T> first;

    public LinkedList(T element=default(T)) { 
        if (element != default(T)) **<---- problem here**
            first = new Node<T>(element);
    }

}
```

I am trying to create a LinkedList empty in case that nothing is pass as parameter and in the other case , create the linkedList in which the content of the param will be the content of the first node.

Some solution to this problem ?

Thanks a lot , Regards

Comment: And what is the problem with the code tha tyou have?

Comment: try adding `where T : class`. not every type is valid for `default(T)`. also, post the actual compile error.

Comment: @DLeh Presumably he should be able to put value types into his linked list as well as classes.  `default(T)` works for all types (except pointers I think).

Comment: I understand this could be for a home work assignment or for just experimentation, but C# already has a linked list.

Comment: The reason you're getting an error is that the `!=` and `==` operators have to be defined for the types you're comparing. Since you cannot add a generic constraint saying that `T` needs to have a `==` or `!=` operator defined, the compiler cannot compile the code. Please note that generics are compile-time guarantees.

Comment: A `params` parameter would make distinguishing these cases easy, via the length of the array, but you'd also need to handle the many-value cases.

Comment: @Strilanc I will try use params and see if it works, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two constuctors:

```
public LinkedList() { 
}

public LinkedList(T element=default(T)) { 
    first = new Node<T>(element);
}
```

problem solved :-)

If you really want to do a comparison (something I wouldn't suggest, but the PC is yours):

```
public LinkedList(T element=default(T)) { 
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    if (!comparer.Equals(element, default(T))) 
        first = new Node<T>(element);
}
```

To give an example of why it is wrong... [0 (zero)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28number%29) is a beautiful number... So round... without ugly corners, a little like the `8` :-), it's said that arabs "invented" it, and it's central to modern math. Now... `default(int) == 0`. Sad.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew that a solution is build another constructor, but I thought I can use method overloading for that. I guess I have to solve it like in old times

Answer (score 1):

Just use 2 constructors:

```
class LinkedList<T>
{

    Node<T> first;

    public LinkedList(T element) 
    { 
        first = new Node<T>(element);
    }

    public LinkedList() 
    { 

    }

}
```